# Is it possible to modify this to remove all <img> tags before adding the new one

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I have included part of my javascript below and what I want to know is upon success it adds an image to the editor. But how do I make it first remove all images from the editor before adding the new one?

```
onComplete: function (file, json) {
  $('#upload-image').attr('disabled', false);
  $('.error-upload').remove();
  if (json['success']) {
    alert(json['success']);
    var oEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.forum_signature;
    var value = document.getElementById('forum_signature').value;
    if (oEditor.mode == 'wysiwyg') {
      oEditor.insertHtml('<img src="' + json['image'] + '" alt="Image" /><p>&nbsp;</p>');
    } else {
      alert('You must be in WYSIWYG mode!');
    }
  }
  if (json['error']) {
    $('#upload').after('<span class="error-upload" style="color:red;">' + json['error'] + '</span>');
  }
  if (json['error_size']) {
    $('#upload').after('<span class="error-upload" style="color:red;">' + json['error_size'] + '</span>');
  }
  $('.loading').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`oEditor` is an instance of `CKEDITOR.editor` class. Therefore this is the right solution:

```
if ( oEditor.mode == 'wysiwyg' && oEditor.editable() ) {
    var images = oEditor.editable().getElementsByTag( 'img' );

    while ( images.count() ) {
        var image = images.getItem( 0 ); // This is a live collection.
        // Whether this is a real image, not e.g. anchor icon.
        if ( image.data( 'cke-saved-src' ) )
            image.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually works. I'm impressed that you work with CKE even on the weekends :)

Comment: @Nanotlep: Nup - helping people on SO is not my job ;) I'm doing this voluntarily :D.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work something out with success. basicall there are two methods in CKEditor that I used.

getData();
setData();

First I got the data from the instance. I attached it to a temporary created dom-element. After that I am able to manipulate the content.
After done the manipulations, I get the html content of the temprorary dom-element and use setData() to place it in the CKEditor. It may be hacky and I am not sure if this is really the correct way, but it does work.

The instance of the editor:

```
var forum_signature = CKEDITOR.replace('textAreaName');
var oEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.forum_signature

var jsonImage = 'images/img2.jpg';
var temp = $("<div/>", {
    id: "temp"
});

var data = oEditor.getData();
$(data).appendTo(temp);
// you now can traverse the "temp" element in the dom
$(temp).find("img").eq(0).remove();

// You can add html
$(temp).append('<img src=' + jsonImage + ' alt="Image" /><p>Hello World</p>');
var newData = $(temp).html();
$(temp).remove();
oEditor.setData(newData);
```

Comment: Where do i put that as i tried above `oEditor.insertHtml('<img src="' + json['image'] + '" alt="Image" /><p>&nbsp;</p>');` and all the images remain

Comment: @Ghodmode - When examining the code in the question, I do have reason to believe he is using jQuery. As far as the second argument, do you have a theory to back that up?

Comment: I'm sorry about that.  I misunderstood your solution.  I thought you were suggesting setting the `src` property to an empty string or a non-existent URI in order to make them not visible.

Comment: No, just replace it. Since the tag is already there and he wants to inject a new one, there is no purpose in removing it. .. cheers ;)

Comment: @Justine - Sorry 'bout that. The CKEditor does seem to require a defined approach. In the docs I can see you will probably have to use the setData() method from CKEditor: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#setData

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$(oEditor).children("img").remove();
```

Comment: Where do i put that as i tried above `oEditor.insertHtml('<img src="' + json['image'] + '" alt="Image" /><p>&nbsp;</p>');` and all the images remain

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure that oEditor is not a DOM node. It seems to be some CKEditor-specific object.

Comment: Ya @HannesJohansson is right, in which case, my non-jQuery solution below won't work either.  You need to identify the DOM object that actually contains the images.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.  It finds all of the `img` elements inside of your oEditor element and removes them from their parent...

```
if ( oEditor.mode == 'wysiwyg' )
{
    // Create an array of img elements.
    imgs = oEditor.getElementsByTagName("img");
    // Remove each img from its parent node.
    for (var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
        imgs[i].parentNode.removeChild(imgs[i]);
    }
    oEditor.insertHtml( '<img src="'+ json['image'] +'" alt="Image" /><p>&nbsp;</p>' );
}
else{
    alert( 'You must be in WYSIWYG mode!' );
}
```

Comment: Tried that and it doesnt do anything not even allow my image to be inserted.

Comment: The problem is what I didn't realize at first.  The oEditor object is not an element in your web page.  You need to find the element that contains the image elements you want to remove.  You haven't shown us enough of your code to help you do that.